# Query doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a login form that asks for a username, a password and a file that contains a key string.
I want to compare the key in this file with the key on my database and if everything matches, the user logins.
The problem is that this query doesn't seem to work:

```
$userBusca = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM account.login_admin WHERE login='".$login."' AND password='".$password."' AND key='".$key."'") or die(mysql_error());
if($userBusca->num_rows == 1) {
```

It shows me this error, but my mysqli connection is working:

Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin\auth\login.php on line 3

this is my line 3:

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect($conn, "5.xx.xx.xxx","user","xxxxxx");
```

I'm getting the content of the user file with this:

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$file_name = $file['name'];
$file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $file['size'];
$file_error = $file['error'];
//whitelist
$file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));
$allowed = array('txt', 'cfg');
if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
if ($file_error === 0) {
    if($file_size <= 2097152) {
        $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
        $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $file_name_new;
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
            $key_read_file = $file_destination;
            $key_load = file_get_contents($key_read_file);
            $key = $key_load;
            echo $key;
```

the echo returns the correct result that I want, but for some reason that error keeps popping up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This : `$dbcon = mysqli_connect($conn, "5.xx.xx.xxx","user","xxxxxx");`

should be this : `$dbcon = mysqli_connect("5.xx.xx.xxx","user","xxxxxx");` and this : `mysqli_query($conn`  should be `mysqli_query($dbcon`

Comment: What is `$conn`?  The error is telling you pretty plainly that it's an object, but the function expects a string.

Comment: You have a SQL injection problem. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

First get the function perfectly

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd");
```

So your's will be something like

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("5.xx.xx.xxx","user","xxxxxx","your_db");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) and [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extensions, which will not work.
You need to use.

```
$myConnection= mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db("databasename") or die ("no database");
```

mysqli has many improvements over the original mysql extension

Answer (score 0):

**This :**

```
 $dbcon = mysqli_connect($conn, "5.xx.xx.xxx","user","xxxxxx");
```

**should be this :**

```
 $dbcon = mysqli_connect("5.xx.xx.xxx","user","xxxxxx");
```

**and this :**

```
 mysqli_query($conn
```

**should be this:**

```
 mysqli_query($dbcon
```